# Python - image file not found if run from another directory?

Tags: python, path, pyqt, pyqt5, packaging

I'm a new programmer, and I am creating a desktop application using pyqt. I'm currently working on packaging this for pip installs through pypi. I have a file directory system of:

```
MANIFEST.in
setup.py
src_dir
->main_script.py
->supporting_script1.py
->supporting_script2.py
->codeAssets_dir
--->img1.png
--->img2.png
```

Right now when I pip install my project and I run it from a clean venv, my images are not being displayed properly when I run it from my venv's home directory. However, when I run the project from the source folder (at the same level as codeAssets_dir), the images display as expected. Everything else works fine, and my project can even access the other supporting scripts regardless of where the program is run.

I'm assuming I'm doing something dumb with my image path, since it's clearly not finding it. In my supporting_script, I'm using a relative path `self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('codeAssets_dir/img1.png')`. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should construct path to your files based on `os.path.dirname(__file__)`.